# Install Maria demo

Tags: wordpress

**PHP 7.4**

**WordPress 5.8.1**

I have installed OceanWp.

I can't install Maria demo.

[image]

Trouble shooting doc: https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/55-theme-installation-errors

Current set of plugins (but they have all been installed by OceanWp plugin, so, there may not be any problem here):

[image]

Config:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2048M');
```

And hoster informed me that:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

Log:

> Error log: [Sun Oct 10 09:51:27 2021] [notice] [client 178.66.61.228:43305] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: premium in /home/g/grablmz2/tech/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra/includes/panel/demos.php on line 990, referer http://grablmz2.beget.tech/wp-admin/admin.php?page=oceanwp-panel-install-demos

But this is not a PRO demo:

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?